# Hexcells save location

Tags: hexcells

Hexcells doesn't support Steam Cloud saves so I'd like to backup my game save manually. Where can I find my user preference and progress files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Windows** is [in the registry](http://steamcommunity.com/app/265890/discussions/0/540734254964999893/#c540734792101999189): `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Matthew Brown\Hexcells` (you can export/import it by right-clicking)

**Linux**: `~/.config/unity3d/Matthew Brown/Hexcells`